# API response time in Android app and postman is different

Tags: android

When I call the API in Postman with a header(Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and a parameter, it gets responses within 2-3 seconds. But when I call the same API with the same header (Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and parameter from my Android code, it takes 12-13 seconds. I am using Volley library, and tried in Retrofit also, but getting the same problem. How can I solved this response time differences problem? Please help me.

Comment: getting the same issues with kotlin for 365dynamic api